# Get field from json using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following json document:

```
{  
   "videoUrl":"",
   "available":"true",
   "movie":{  
      "videoUrl":"http..."
   },
   "account":{  
      "videoUrl":"http...",
      "login":"",
      "password":""
   }
}
```

In this json I have a property named videoUrl, I want to get first non empty videoUrl

My regex:

```
("videoUrl":)("http.+")
```

But this regex match the following String

```
    "videoUrl" :"http..."},
"account" : {"videoUrl" : "http...","login" : "","password" : ""
```

What is my way to write Regex that will find first non empty videoUrl with it's value

(Result should be `"videoUrl":"http..."`)

Comment: I don't think you need any regex but json parsing and logic

Comment: try adding `\s` (whitespace) at the end of your expression.

Comment: @JanOssowski Thank for response, I add , but still it's not correct

Comment: @B001ᛦ The problem is that I dont have i json in the begging, I parse .js script which include this json as part of the code

Comment: Parsing json by regex is not a good idea. Could you try jsonPath? https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `(?!,)` at the end of the regex, it will make the regex stop at an `,` without capturing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "{  \n" +
            "   \"videoUrl\":\"\",\n" +
            "   \"available\":\"true\",\n" +
            "   \"movie\":{  \n" +
            "      \"videoUrl\":\"http...\"\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   \"account\":{  \n" +
            "      \"videoUrl\":\"http...\",\n" +
            "      \"login\":\"\",\n" +
            "      \"password\":\"\"\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "} ";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"videoUrl\":)(\"http.+\")(?!,)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());  // "videoUrl":"http..."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It will be more appropriate to use one of JSON parsers, like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or Jackson, instead of regex. Something like:

```
String jsonStr = "...";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
String url = element.get("videoUrl").getAsString();
```