# Find the value from json string using regex in java

Tags: java, json

```
[{
  "field1": "",
  "field2": "I got you",
  "field3": [],
  "field4": ""
}]
```

My objective is to read only the field2 value. How can I do it using regex in java?

Comment: Note that JSON is not a regular language and thus regular expressions aren't a good or safe fit. You _could_ use it but unless you really know what the value of `field2` can be you'll eventually run into problems and even a very complex expression might not always do what you want. Better use a proper parser and extract the value (e.g. use Jackson's `ObjectMapper.readTree(json)` to get a generic representation of your JSON).

Comment: Why not use a library that reads it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to treat JSON as any regular String, I'd say it's a better idea to extract the value using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). For your example it would look like this:

```
String json = ...;
String value2 = JsonPath.read(json, "$[0].field2");
```

The dollar sign stands for the root element, `[0]` is the first element of the array and field2 the name of the field you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486394/get-field-from-json-using-regex).

You can see [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/81631441394/) for example if you realy want to use Regex.

But as [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) says (in first comment to your post), better solution will be use json parser, examples you can see in [this article](https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/).